# Error creating an AlertDialog in an onClick

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to share a content on facebook when clicking on my share button

i've trouble creating an alert dialog in an onclick,

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.actuDetailsShareButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActuDetailActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Partagez sur facebook");
            WebView facebookWV = new WebView(ActuDetailActivity.this);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            facebookWV.setLayoutParams(lp);
            facebookWV.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.lalal.com");
            builder.setView(facebookWV);
            builder.show();

            }
        });
```

here is my logcat :

```
03-27 19:18:23.007: E/AndroidRuntime(24773): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

here is my second try :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActuDetailActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.share_alert_dialog_layout);
                dialog.setTitle("lolol");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.shareAlertDialogTextView)).setText("share on facebook");
                ((WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.shareAlertDialogWebView)).loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.lalal.com");
                dialog.show();
```

but my webView open itself in an other activity, that's not what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YouActivityName.this);

    (... some code here...)

builder.show();
```

And you have to [setWebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) like this:

```
WebView facebookWV = new WebView(YouActivityName.this);
facebookWV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

facebookWV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i've got the same effect than my second try, my webview is built in an other activity

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `Context` you supply to the `AlertDialog` from `getBaseContext()` to `YourActivityName.this`.

Comment: the error changes : 
 Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @RenaudFavier Well I don't know what you are trying to do, so add that flag to the `Intent` you use in `startActivity()`.

Comment: no no i'm not trying to start any activity, i just wan't to display a webview in my alertdialog, i'm not doing anything else than what i'm showing to you

Comment: @RenaudFavier Have you also added the `YourActivityName.this` to your `WebView` constructor instead of `getBaseContext()` ?